# For Java testing, should I mock client or mock the server

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, integration-testing

In the client-server architecture, what should be the best approach when one should mock the client and when one should mock the server. I understand that unit tests should only test given class, with every dependent object mocked, while integration tests should test a feature as a whole. When it comes to the API calls, I am puzzled should I mock the client that I use for api calls or should I use some server mocking framework and let the real client call the mock server.

I have a situation where I should (it is not mandatory) test if I hit the proper API url, with proper method and with certain values passed in query parameters or in request body. With client mocking, I can simply "verify" if given parameters (path, method, request body) are passed and consider test successful. If I am to mock the server, then I need to create a little bit of processing on mock server to check if path, method and request body are correctly passed and return a value. In this case, server response is the only thing that I can use to measure if test is successful (send 500 if required data is not received).

By your experience, what is the proper way to test calls in client-server architecture for integration testing? If we go by the book, then server mocking should be used, but is that practical in the above mentioned case? For unit testing it is clear that mocks should be used.

**Update:** To avoid confusion: I am making a client that depends on the publicly available service which I cannot control. So, I am testing if the client is working properly and focus is on the client. Question is related should I (in integration-tests) mock the client object that is responsible for remote connections(In my case WSClient from Play framework), or should I use some server mock (like okhttp mock web server).

**Another update:** Most people suggest that simple rule of the thumb should be followed: if these are the unit tests then mock the client and if these are the integration tests then use mock server. Now, I am curious about this situation: I have a class A that has dependency on class B and class B has a client object that is tasked with remote calls. If I was to write unit test for class A, I should mock the class B and that is fine. However, if I am doing integration testing for class A, is it acceptable to mock client object in class B and "verify" if proper parameters are passed to it (path, method and request body), or, for the sake of completeness, I should run the mock server even if mocking the client object is easier. In this case, I will not test for timeouts and low level network errors. Or the whole point of integration testing, in this case, should be to test network connectivity as well.

Comment: Which component is the current test being written for? "Server" is a very fluid concept in this case. Your server components could be consuming other HTTP services, thereby becoming a client for which it makes sense to mock servers. If the focus of the test is the client, then you can mock the server. Here your question becomes a little unclear. But if the concern is about mocking components of the system that you should be testing, then maybe you should look into service virtualization tools for stubbing external requests using proxies (mock-server, hoverfly, etc.)

Comment: I tend to use junit to drive non trivial tests which are a minimum testable unit (even if that means running a client and server in process)

Comment: I should have probably defined that better in the question: I am making a client that depends on the publicly available service which I cannot control. So, I am testing if the client is working properly and focus is on the client.

Answer (score 4):

You need:

1. Integration tests - use stub server like Wiremock, test real scenarios like timeouts, malformed response, 500 etc.
2. Test your client class - mock server endpoint using Mockito and verify response

Comment: Ok, so you are suggesting that the purpose of the integration tests should be test network connectivity and various responses that server could send to back. For #2 I don't quite understand what do you mean with testing your client class: are you referring to the unit-testing (in which case server mocking do not make much sense), or are you referring to the another type of testing in which I should only test to verify what I am sending?

Comment: You initially asked how to check if your client hit proper api endpoint with params. The answear is : just mock this endpoint with Mockito, I will not tell you how since I dont know what frameworks you are using. That would be unit test for your client class. Using stub server you can do real end to end test. That is neccessary and that is integration testing in my opinion. Did I help you ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Generally, my question was related which approach is preferred: to mock client calls or mock the server. How to do that is not the part of the question. Most people suggest that simple rule of the thumb should be followed: if these are the unit tests then mock the client and if these are the integration tests then use mock server. I will update the question to be more precise.